# Python threading global variable issue

Tags: python, multithreading, global-variables

I have a few scripts that i want to run simultaneously, they read a CSV file,  im trying the following;

```
import sys
import csv

out = open("C:\PYDUMP\PYDUMPINST.csv","r")
dataf=csv.reader(out)

for row in dataf:
    take   = row[0]
    give   = row[1]


def example():

      try:
          lfo = int(take)
          if lfo > 0:

          #code

      except Exception, e:
          pass    
example()
```

This is saved as takefile1.py. I have 20 scripts with similar structures that i want to run simultaneously. So im using(which i have been using for running other batches of scripts trouble free) the following;

```
import csv
import sys
from threading import Thread


def firstsend_lot():

        execfile("C:\Users\takefile1.py")                                    

        execfile("C:\Users\takefile2.py") 


def secondsend_lot():  


        execfile("C:\Users\takefile3.py")                                    

        execfile("C:\Users\takefile4.py") 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target = firstsend_lot).start()
    Thread(target = secondsend_lot).start()
```

So i am getting the error "global name 'take' is not defined". Anyone got any suggestions? Im pretty hopeless at Python so pretend you are talking to an idiot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function example(), do not have access to take. Try adding a line in it:

```
def example():
      global take
      try:
          lfo = int(take)
          if lfo > 0:

          #code

      except Exception, e:
          pass
```

Comment: Excellent Ivaylo, thanks for your time, much appreciated. One simple example can better 10 pages of python help pages. Whoever designed that python help must be having a laugh.

Comment: @user3439187, if you like the reply, just upvote it mate. It says more than 10 'thank you')

Comment: @Konstantin, i have tried but i need more points to up-vote someone, i need 15 points and i only have 2. So thank you will have to do for now im afraid. Why don't you up-vote my question and give me points!! :) I jest, of course.

Comment: @user3439187: I am glad that the solution helped.You cannot up-vote the question, but you can approve my answer. That is how the system works. By approving my answer your reputation goes up as well.

Comment: Actually it is a deadlock. Only you in this universe can approve any valid answer (by approve I mean clicking on the symbol below the number to accept an answer).